# Specific Link Click Query

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am trying to create a query that will pull the unique clicks on a specific link within in the email and also pull acct_number on a daily basis and then do an extract of the DE.  I do not need to have Subscriber Key or Email appended to the file.  Since this is a file that will be used for a different purpose the less bulky the better. So far I have been able to build a query that will get all of the link click but not a specific link or acct_number to be included. I have been able to get subscriber key but I still need acct_number. Current query:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT o.SubscriberKey as Subscriber_Key 
    ,o.JobID as job_id
    ,o.EventDate as click_date
    ,o.IsUnique as is_unique
    FROM _Click o
    JOIN _Job j
    ON o.JobID = j.JobID
    JOIN _Subscribers sub
    ON sub.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID
    AND CAST(o.EventDate as date) >= CAST(getdate()-1 as date)
    WHERE o.JobID IN (
    '10119480'
    )
    AND o.IsUnique = 'false'
```

Comment: Can you specify what acct_number is? Is this the Business Unit, SubscriberID, Campaign, something Custom? Is this really a field of salesforce MARKETING CLOUD?

Comment: This field is held in the preferences of all subscribers and is imported along with the rest of the subscribers information. While its not a subscriber key,  it is a unique identifier to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have comment privileges yet, but I don't know from your question why the IsUnique would be false and where the subscribers sit.  So I am making a couple of assumptions here in that there's a subscriber or audience DE, and that we can pull a larger amount of data as a baseline.  If so, this query should pull out all of the data relating to people who have clicked on a specified URL in a specified send.  If you need to make this distinct per subscriber, it should be possible to tweak the code to make this so.

```
SELECT a.SubscriberKey as Subscriber_Key 
,a.acct_number
,c.JobID as job_id
,c.EventDate as click_date
,c.IsUnique as is_unique
,c.URL
FROM _Click c
INNER JOIN Audience a
ON a.SubscriberKey = c.SubscriberKey
WHERE c.JobID = [JobID of Send]
AND c.URL = [Link that you are trying to track]
```

Comment: Where are you getting Audience from? I think the trouble that i am having is appending the acct_number that should be stored in both the All Subscribers and the Clicks. I have verified that this attribute lives in All Subscribers and when I look to export the clicks manually it is also provided. I have also tried to bring in the Data Extension where there will be acct_account number present but again the trouble is joining the information with the Clicks/All Subs.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(c.SubscriberKey) as Subscriber_Key, 
c.JobID as job_id,
                c.EventDate as click_date,
                c.IsUnique as is_unique,
                d.acct_number as acct_number
    FROM _Click o
    JOIN _Job j on (c.JobID = j.JobID)
    JOIN ent._Subscribers sub on (sub.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID AND CAST(o.EventDate as date) >= CAST(getdate()-1 as date))
    JOIN UAT_Survey_Seed_List d on (c.acct_number = d.acct_number)
    WHERE o.JobID IN ('10091444')
    AND o.IsUnique = 'false'
    AND o.URL IN ('www.wawarewards.com')`

Comment: I got audience from making an assumption that you have an audience or subscriber DE.  AFAIK it's not possible to add fields to data views.